# Calculate area drawn outside of canvas boundaries

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Suppose I have a canvas object with a set width and height of 400 each, and I draw outside the boundaries of the canvas object in it's 2d context. Is there a way to calculate the size of anything that has been drawn outside of the canvas boundaries?

Example illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Bounding area of all rects**

Calculate the extrema of all rectangles:

```
var currentLeftmostX=10000000;
var currentTopmostY=10000000;
var currentRightmostX=-10000000;
var currentBottommostY=-10000000;

// do this for each rect
if( rect.x < currentLeftmostX) {currentLeftmostX=rect.x;}
if( rect.y < currentTopmostY) {currentTopmostY=rect.y;}
if( rect.x+rect.width > currentRightmostX) {currentRightmostX=rect.x;}
if( rect.y+rect.height > currentBottommostY){currentBottommostY=rect.y;}

var boundingArea=
    (currentRightmostX-currentLeftmostX)*(currentBottommostY - currentBottommostY);
```